# Use Dart/Flutter with Seq Log Center

Tags: dart, logging, seq, seq-logging

We're already using a Seq Docker Container to having .NET logs centralized in Web UI.
Now I have a dart / flutter application and don't find any adapter for usage that stack with Seq.

On Homepage there is named the following one's to be supported:

Seq accepts logs via HTTP, GELF, custom inputs, and the seqcli command-line client, with plug-ins or integrations available for .NET Core, Java, Node.js, Python, Ruby, Go, Docker, message queues, and many other technologies.

So my question is now, if I can easily support Dart within Seq for saving Logs etc. without writing everything completely new.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a Dart client library for Seq. Perhaps you could use the [Dart JS interop](https://dart.dev/web/js-interop) and one of the [Seq JavaScript clients](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/using-nodejs)?